# Laravel 4.2 ORM Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, orm

I get this error when i try to run my query.

> BadMethodCallException 
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()

My Search Controller that looks in the database for specific projects based on URI http://localhost:8000/search/projects/email_category/foo@foo.com_spel+kod-game+code

```
class SearchController extends BaseController {
  //foo.com/search/project/email_category/foo@foo.com-admin@foo.com_spel+kod-game+code
  public function index($option, $key, $val){
    $keys = explode('_', $key);
    $vals = explode('_', $val);
    $data = [];

    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($keys); $i++){
      $data[$keys[$i]] = explode('-', $vals[$i]);
    }
    $json = json_encode($data);
    echo "<pre>" . $option . ": " . $json . "</pre>";

    // Get all rows in option table, but we are going to sort things out before calling it with ->get();
    $table = DB::table($option);
    foreach($data as $key => $value){
      foreach($value as $string){
        $split = explode('+', $string);
        foreach ($split as $explode){
          if(end($split) !== $explode){
            switch($key){
              case 'email':
                $table->with(array('User' => function($query) use ($key, $explode){
                  $query->where('email',"=",$explode);
                }));
                    break;
              case 'categories':
                $table->Category->where('typ',"=",$explode);
                break;
              default:
                $table->where($key,"=",$explode);
                    break;
            }
          }
        }
        switch($key){
          case 'email':
            $table->with(array('User' => function($query) use ($explode){
              $query->orWhere('email',"=",$explode);
            }));
            break;
          case 'categories':
            $table->Category->orWhere('typ',"=",$explode);
            break;
          default:
            $table->orWhere($key,"=",$explode);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
    $table->get(); // Runs the query we have build up.

  }
}
```

User Model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function project() 
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Project');
    }

    public function experience()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Experience');
    }

    public function reference()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Reference');
    }

    public function stat()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Stat');
    }

}
```

Project Model

```
<?php

class Project extends Eloquent 
{

protected $table = 'projects';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
    }

    public function stat()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Stat');
    }
}
```

I have tried to follow some examples from Laravels webpage.
I made a test string query that show'd the correct string but now i need it in ORM. I have tried my self to solve this for some days now and i have never posted anything in Stackoverflow before so if you find something unclear just comments and i will add it.

Comment: I am not 100 % sure, but I don't think `with()` can be used on `DB::table()` calls - only with models extending Eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that will fix everything but for starters use your model instead of `DB::table()`:

```
// ...

$model = studly_case($option);
$table = new $model;

// ...
```